# NUnit Attribute to simulate condition-based Assert.Inconclusive with custom message text

Tags: attributes, nunit, custom-attributes

I have some tests that depend on a certain thing being true (access to the internet, as it happens, but that isn't important and I don't want to discuss the details of the condition).

I can very easily write a static helper method which will test the (parameterless) condition and call `Assert.Inconclusive("Explanatory Message")` if it's `true`/`false`. And then call that at the start of each `Test` which has this requirement.

But I'd like to do this as an `Attribute`, if possible.

---

**How, in detail, do I achieve that, in NUnit?**

---

## *What I've tried so far:*

There's an [`IApplyToTest` interface](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/IApplyToTest-Interface), exposed by NUnit, which I can make my Attribute implement, and will allow me to hook into the TestRunner, but I can't get it to do what I want :(

That interface gives me access to an `NUnit.Framework.Internal.Test` object.

If I call:

> `test.RunState = RunState.NotRunnable;`

then I get something equivalent to `Assert.Fail("")`.

Similarly `RunState.Skipped` or `RunState.Ignored` give me the equivalent of `Assert.Ignore("")`.

But none of these are setting a message on the Test, and there's no `test.Message = "foo";` or equivalent (that I can see).

There's a `test.MakeInvalid("Foo")` which *does* set a message, but that's equivalent to `Assert.Fail("Foo")`.

I found something that looked promising:

```
var result = test.MakeTestResult();
result.SetResult(ResultState.Inconclusive, "Custom Message text");
```

But that doesn't seem to *do* anything; the Test just Passes :( I looked for a `test.SetAsCurrentResult(result)` method in case I need to "attach" that result object back to the test? But nothing doing.

It feels like this is supposed to be possible, but I can't quite figure out how to make it all play together.

---

If anyone can even show me how to get to `Skipped` + `Custom Message displayed`, then I'd probably take that!

Comment: Note that I'm open to other ways of achieving "Simulate `Assert.Inconclusive()` from a custom `Attribute`", naturally.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want your test to be `Inconclusive`, then that's what `Assume.That` is there for. Use it just as you would use `Assert.That` and the specified constraint fails, your test result will be inconclusive.

That would be the simplest answer to your question.

However, reading the things you have tried, I don't think you actually want `Inconclusive` at least not as it is defined by NUnit.

In NUnit, `Inconclusive` means that the test doesn't count because it couldn't be run. The result basically disappears and the test run is successful.

You seem to be saying that you want to receive some notice that the condition failed. That makes sense in the situation where (for example) the internet was not available so your test run isn't definitive.

NUnit provides `Assert.Ignore` and `Warn.If` (also `Warn.Unless`) for those situations. Or you can set the corresponding result states in your custom attribute.

Regarding implementation... The `RunState` of a test applies to it's status before anyone has even tried to execute it. So, for example, the `RunState` may be Ignored if someone has used the `IgnoreAttribute` or it may be NotRunnable if it requires arguments and none are provided. There is no `Inconclusive` run sttate because that would mean the test is written to be inconclusive all the time, which makes no ssense. The `IApplyToTest` interface allows an attribute to change the status of a test at the point of discovery, before it is even run, so you would not want to use that.

**After** NUnit has attempted to run a test, it gets a `ResultState`, which might be Inconclusive. You can affect this in the code of the test but not currently through an attribute. What you want here is something that checks the conditions needed to run the test immediately before running it and skips execution if the conditions are not met. That attribute would need to be one that generates a command in the chain of commands that execute a test. It would probably need to implement `ICommandWrapper` to do that, which is a bit more complicated than `IApplyToTest` because the attribute code must generate a command instance that will work properly with NUnit itself and with other commands in the chain.

If I had this situation, I believe I would use a Run parameter to indicate whether the internet should be available. Then, the tests could

```
Assume.That(InternetIsNotNeeded());
```

silently ignoring those tests or fail as expected when the internet should be available.

Comment: I don't know why you're trying to tell me what it is that I want to achieve, in the first place, but `Inconclusive means that the test doesn't count because it couldn't be run` sounds like a _perfect_ description of what's going on in this case.

Comment: You seem to have given a lot of options for other ways to achieve this with a method call in the test. But as per my question I already know _exactly_ how I would achieve that (indeed, that's what I'm currently doing). So I'm not sure why you've offered other ways to do that.

Comment: `There is no Inconclusive RunState because that would mean the test is written to be inconclusive all the time, which makes no sense.` Nonsense. By that logic there would be no `RunState.Ignored` or `Skipped` either. The `IApplyToTest` exists specifically to allow dynamic manipulation of these states.

Comment: You appear to present an argument which concludes that nothing in `IApplyToTest` could set a message in the Result, but (again, as per the question) `test.MakeInvalid(text)` already does exactly that, so it's clearly not inherently impossible by concept.

Comment: Please re-read my answer with the idea in mind that I'm writing about how NUnit is designed to work -  and therefore works best. I do know a bit about that, having designed this feature in the first place, although I may not understand correctly what you want.

Comment: MY comment that you don't actually seem to want NUnit's Inconclusive is based on your saying the tests seemed to pass. That's pretty much what they do for an inconclusive result. I don't know how you run the tests, but most runners don't call any attention to an Inconclusive test. So if you want attention called, you are probably better served by Ignored or Warning result.